# Python Numba issue (TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline)

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I just started getting familiar with how to accelerate my code with Numba, so I was testing very simple functions:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from time import time

@jit(nopython = True)
def dotter(X):
    Z = np.dot(X,X.T)
    return(Z)

tic = time()
dotter(X)
toc = time()
print(1000*(toc-tic), ' ms')
X = np.random.randint(1, 1000, (1000, 1))
```

And I get this error message:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-8-ae7154a2d7d0> in <module>
>       1 tic = time()
> ----> 2 dotter(X)
>       3 toc = time()
>       4 print(1000*(toc-tic), ' ms')
> 
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py in
> _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
>     418                 e.patch_message(msg)
>     419 
> --> 420             error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
>     421         except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
>     422             # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
> 
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py in
> error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
>     359                 raise e
>     360             else:
> --> 361                 raise e.with_traceback(None)
>     362 
>     363         argtypes = []
> 
> TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython
> frontend) No implementation of function Function(<function dot at
> 0x7fdbf7c19670>) found for signature:
>  
>  >>> dot(array(int64, 2d, C), array(int64, 2d, F))   There are 2 candidate implementations:
>       - Of which 2 did not match due to:
>       Overload in function 'dot': File: numba/core/typing/npydecl.py: Line 957.
>         With argument(s): '(array(int64, 2d, C), array(int64, 2d, F))':
>        Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
>          TypingError: np.dot() only supported on float and complex arrays   raised from
> /Users/Zsolti/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/typing/npydecl.py:942
> 
> During: resolving callee type: Function(<function dot at
> 0x7fdbf7c19670>) During: typing of call at
> <ipython-input-7-093e59547e26> (3)
> 
> 
> File "<ipython-input-7-093e59547e26>", line 3: def dotter(X):
>     Z = np.dot(X,X.T)
>     ^
```

I changed the X definition to np.random.rand() and fixed the problem, bu still don't understand why numba can not understand random.randint.
Can somebody explain it to me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be here: `TypingError: np.dot() only supported on float and complex arrays`

Numba works by re-implementing a subset of Numpy. See [the docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html). In this case, it seems that `np.dot` is not implemented for integer types, which is what you get from `np.random.randint`. This is also true for `np.matmul`.

So, to JIT this with Numba, you'll first have to convert to a float array. Note that this is slower than the pure python implementation. Also note the early call to `dotter`. This triggers the JIT compiler so that the compilation time is not included with your timer.

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from time import time

@jit(nopython = True)
def dotter(X):
    Z = np.dot(X,X.T)
    return(Z)

X = np.random.randint(1, 1000, (1000, 1)).astype(float)
z = dotter(X)

tic = time()
z = dotter(X).astype(int)
toc = time()
print(1000*(toc-tic), ' ms')
```

Numba really shines when you have python for loops that can be compiled. In this use case, it is just as likely to slow you down as it is to speed things up.